# Keeping user logged in - FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am having the hardest time figuring this out. I am using FormAuthentication. When a user logs in and they check remember me, I want to the user to stay logged in for 24 hours. The problem is, no matter what I do the user is automatically logged out after like 30 minutes. We the user selected remember me, I set a persistent cookie to expire 24 hours later. I can see the cookie in the browser options and the expiration is correct. If I leave the site and go back in say an hour. The user is logged out...... He is some code snippets of what I have.

```
bool IsValid = Membership.ValidateUser(LoginControl.UserName, LoginControl.Password);

if (IsValid)
{
    e.Authenticated = true;

    if (LoginControl.RememberMeSet)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(LoginControl.UserName, true, 1440); // 1 day
        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        cookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
        Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(LoginControl.UserName, true), true);
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(LoginControl.UserName, true);
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginControl.UserName, true);
    }
    else
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(LoginControl.UserName, false);
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginControl.UserName, false);
    }
}
```

Here is my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="/" timeout="1" cookieless="UseCookies"  protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40"/>
</authentication>
```

When a user does not check remember me, I set a non-persistent cookie and after 1 minute of inactivity the user logs out. This is working correctly. The problem is when a remember cookie is set and the user returns the user is not logged in anymore even though a cookie is there.

Comment: You will need to set the session timeout programmatically to override either the setting in your web.config or the default setting if not included in web.config. Session cookies are handled automatically for you so setting a cookie will not provide a solution (as you have found out).

Comment: FastGeek, so the way I am setting the cookie above is not correct?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6):

Set the following session state time out in web.config. By default, session timeout is 20 minutes.

```
<system.web>
   ...
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="1440" />
   </authentication>
   ...  
   <sessionState timeout="1440"/>
   ...
</system.web>
```

### Solution

Set authentication cookie using default ticket setting if user checks remember me. Otherwise, create AuthenticationTicket by yourself.

```
string username = LoginControl.UserName;

if (LoginControl.RememberMeSet)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, true);
}
else
{
    var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(username, true, 1);
    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
        encryptedTicket)
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
        Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
        Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain,
        Expires = authTicket.Expiration
    };
    Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

    // ***** Here is the fix *****
    // Do not use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie or RedirectFromLoginPage
    // if you create own FormsAuthenticationTicket.
    Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
}
```

### Testing

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var id = (FormsIdentity) User.Identity;
        var ticket = id.Ticket;
        sb.Append("Authenticated");
        sb.Append("<br/>CookiePath: " + ticket.CookiePath);
        sb.Append("<br/>Expiration: " + ticket.Expiration);
        sb.Append("<br/>Expired: " + ticket.Expired);
        sb.Append("<br/>IsPersistent: " + ticket.IsPersistent);
        sb.Append("<br/>IssueDate: " + ticket.IssueDate);
        sb.Append("<br/>Name: " + ticket.Name);
        sb.Append("<br/>UserData: " + ticket.UserData);
        sb.Append("<br/>Version: " + ticket.Version);
        Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
    else
        Label1.Text = "Not Authenticated";
}
```

To be honest with you, Session and Authentication Cookie time out 1 minute is too low, but it is up to you.

In addition, please a note in web.config that you create AuthenticationTicket yourself. Next person who debug your code will definitely appreciate it.

### Problem (Updated)

If we create **FormsAuthenticationTicket** ourself, we should not use **FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage** which will override our custom expire date and uses the one from web.config.

Comment: AI am glad you mentioned this because I set the sessionState to time out in 1 minutes also. The session still last for 20 minutes. Why is this?

Comment: This is what I have in the web.config

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="/" timeout="1" cookieless="UseCookies"  protection="All" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>

    

    <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="1440" />

Now with this setup like this and with the code in my original post. If the user selects remember me, they are staying logged in but if they don't check remember me they are getting logged out after 1 minute of inactivity.

Comment: Actually I just tested, If I do it your way, even if the user does not check the remember box, they stay logged in longer than the 1 minute. I logged in and did not check remember me, closed the browser and reopened after 5 minutes, the user is still logged in. Any idea?

Comment: I updated the answer. The problem is if we create FormsAuthenticationTicket ourself, we should not use `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` which will override our custom expire date and uses the one from web.config. I tested and it expires accordingly.

Comment: I just tested the above code and still remember me does not stay logged in.

Comment: I tested with all browsers and they are working fine. Could you clear browser cache and test it again? In addition, I added a testing code to check auth ticket expire time.

Comment: I did what you said but it's not working. It's working the way I am doing it.

Comment: It works fine on me. Could you please create a sample project and test it?