# UserData property of FormsAuthenticationTicket is empty despite being set

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

For some reason, I the UserData property of my authentication cookie is empty. Here is the code:

```
var authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, rememberUser.Checked);
// Get the FormsAuthenticationTicket out of the encrypted cookie
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
// Create a new FormsAuthenticationTicket that includes our custom User Data
var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, "userData");
// Update the authCookie's Value to use the encrypted version of newTicket
authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
// Manually add the authCookie to the Cookies collection
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, rememberUser.Checked);
```

Here is how I try to access it:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated )
{
    var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        string data = authTicket.UserData;
        // data is empty !!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`RedictFromLoginPage` overwrites your cookie. Remove this line and redirect manually (`Response.Redirect`).

Comment: i am using `Response.Redirect` but still `UserData` got empty string

Comment: i have posted my question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816425/getting-formsauthentication-ticket-userdata-as-empty-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816425/getting-formsauthentication-ticket-userdata-as-empty-string)

Answer (score 3):

This is a similar answer I answered few days ago.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16365000/296861

You cannot use **FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie** or **FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage** if you create **FormsAuthenticationTicket** by yourself.

Comment: I realized that FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl also have this problem. Retrieving the url and storing in into a variable, then setting the cookie  and lastly do the redirect solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you were doing the same tutorial...
i have encountered the same problem
in my case .. it was a web config error..

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60" cookieless="UseUri"/>
  </authentication>
```

if you have cookieless="UseUri" in your web config remove it..
it work in my case

Answer (score 0):

Another reason the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` can wind up with an empty `UserData` value -- which results in the encrypted authentication token generated by calling `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt` on the authentication ticket being empty as well -- is if `null` was specified as the value for the `userData` parameter of the [`FormsAuthenticationTicket` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.-ctor).

If you have no special user data to set on the authentication ticket, then use an empty string as the argument instead of `null`.

That is, instead of:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    myAuthenticationTicketVersion, 
    authenticatedUserName, 
    DateTime.Now, 
    myExpirationDate,
    true, 
    null); // The null value here causes the problem
```

Do this instead:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    myAuthenticationTicketVersion, 
    authenticatedUserName, 
    DateTime.Now, 
    myExpirationDate,
    true, 
    ""); // Ok
```