# cookie not working for remember me in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, web-config

I use this code for login in website:

```
var userId = User.UserId;
var userData = userId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), persistanceFlag, userData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
if (authTicket.IsPersistent)
     {
          cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6);
     }
```

and use machinekey in web.config and this code:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" cookieless="UseCookies" />
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

but remember me is not working! I check cookie in browser, .ASPXAUTH is saved and date expires is ok. but after a few minutes, asp.net not use cookies is browser and remember me not working!

Answer (score 1):

You also want to set cookie expiration same as ticket expiration.

```
...
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
                Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
            };
if (authTicket.IsPersistent)
{
   cookie.Expires = encTicket.Expiration;
}
if (FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain != null)
{
   cookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
}
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

**FYI:** You might want to remove `timeout="20"` and `cookieless="UseCookies"` which are [default values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: please help me for set sessionState and forms in web.config for authentication.

Comment: I remove sessionState and cookieless="UseCookies" in web.config and use your code but remember me not working :-(

Comment: Look at Page_Load event of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16365000/296861) for debugging.